# Create a function like localization in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I want to create a function like **example (str, {msg: text, msg1: text2...}**.

Assume that I have a string like: 

`"hello world I'm {msg}"`

And with JavaScript function, I want to call it like **example (str, {msg: text}**. Then this will give to me; hello world I'm text.

I know this can be handled with replace operation but replace operation doesn't look clear to me. Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string replace like below

```
function stringReplace(string, obj){
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([template,value])=> {
     string = string.replace('{'+template+'}',value);
  });
  return string;
}

let str = "Hello from {test}";

console.log(stringReplace(str,{test: "world"}));
```